# Issue with dual boot Windows 8 and Linux Fedora 26

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, bios, fedora

I am tortured with a bad dual boot situation a few days now.
I had a really crippled - low specs and a poor Celeron N2930 CPU - ACER E15 laptop with windows 8.1 preinstalled which it was a nightmare experience.  So i decided to install my favorite Linux distribution Fedora 26 with gnome 3 graphical inerface. 
Only if it was that easy...After a huge adventure just to set a live USB Fedora bootable from BIOS - A Bios setted on boot UEFFI mode - i finally installed my fedora 26 on a unallocated space of my hard disk that i had made from windows 8.1 disk tool. But of course it was impossible to boot on Fedora 26 since windows boot manager were throwing me instantly to windows 8.1.

I tried with any possible tool to create a entry on windows boot manager for fedora 26 partitions but it was impossible. For a reason no tool not even EasyBCD were recognizing my fedora partitions (/home , / , /etc and more).

Then i got desperate and i did this thing. I booted again from my live Fedora usb stick to reinstall Fedora 26 hoping that i will get Grub2 boot loader instead of windows boot manager.
I did it and now...i cant boot on my windows 8.1. It seems like Windows Boot Manager got entirely overwritten on the partition /boot/effi.
When i a logging on BIOS there is no anymore option to set Windows Boot Manager as the first "device" on the boot seqeuence.

So is any way that i can fix it? I am sure that my windows 8.1 partition dint get overwritten. Linux holds just 80 GB of my hard disk that they were meant for it only. It just doesnt recognize my windows 8.1 partition except the windows 8 recovery partition!

I am attaching some output of fdisk tool and mount log that it might be helpful.

FDISK

[image: fdisk output]

Also i am getting this error message each time that i start up the laptop and i am logging on Fedora

OUTPUT OF JOURNALCTL LOG

```
 Sep 11 16:59:15 localhost.localdomain kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Sep 11 16:59:15 localhost.localdomain kernel: Loaded UEFI:MokListRT cert 'Fedora Secure Boot CA: fde32599c2d61db1bf5807335d7b20e4cd963b42' linked to secondary sys keyring
```

Thank you very much!